# An error occured while executing doInBackground?

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

Here is my code

```
package com.example.rollsystems;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.dto.Student;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import com.example.listview.*;

import com.example.Utils.AllBO;
import com.example.rollsystems.R;

public class RollCallActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Student> array;
    ListStudentAdapter arrayAdapter;
    ListView list;

    TextView txtClassAt;
    TextView txtSubjectAt;
    TextView txtInstructorAt;
    TextView txtTimeAt;
    TextView txtDateAt;
    Context context;

    public class RollCallTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public RollCallActivity activity;

        public RollCallTask(RollCallActivity a)
        {
            activity = a;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("rs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            //String RollCallID = sharedPref.getString("RollCallID", "14");

                String RollCallID = "14";
                list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listAtStudent);
                ArrayList<Student> rollCalls = new AllBO().getRollCallInfo(RollCallID);
                array = rollCalls;

            return  null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            arrayAdapter = new ListStudentAdapter(activity, R.layout.list_atstudent, array);
            list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            txtClassAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClassAt);
        }

    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.tab_rollcall);

            new RollCallTask(this).execute();
            txtClassAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClassAt);

        }


}
```

And then, when i run:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(883): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(883): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
```

every help is precious

Comment: Could you post the whole LogCat, so we can see the exact error

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your doInBackground method and step through it to locate the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the UI from a background thread. You'll need to do that outside of `doInBackground`.

You also must call `AsyncTask` from the UI Thread. Failing to do so is the cause of your runtime error.

```
public class RollCallTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public RollCallActivity activity;

    public RollCallTask(RollCallActivity a)
    {
        activity = a;
    }        

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("rs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //String RollCallID = sharedPref.getString("RollCallID", "14");

        String RollCallID = "14";
        ArrayList<Student> rollCalls = new AllBO().getRollCallInfo(RollCallID);
        array = rollCalls;

        return  null;
    }
}
```

And then your `onCreate` would be

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_rollcall);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listAtStudent);
        txtClassAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClassAt);
        new RollCallTask(this).execute();

    }
```

Comment: Oh okay, I see it now. You're calling another `asynctask` from `doInBackground`. Asynctasks *must* be called from the UI thread or they will throw the `RuntimeException` that you are getting here.

Answer (score 0):

The async task is accessing the UI. Don't do `findViewById` in it, use `onCreate` from the Activity/Fragment.

Here are also several convention issues:

```
String RollCallID = "14";
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listAtStudent);
ArrayList<Student> rollCalls = new AllBO().getRollCallInfo(RollCallID);
array = rollCalls;
```

- variables should never start with an uppercase `rollCallID`
- xml id's should not be camel cased `R.id.list_as_student`
- array is not used outside the adapter, why use a variable outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Handler object from your MainActivity and post a runnable. To use it from the backgrund you need to make the object a static that you can call outside of your MainActivity or you can create a static instance of the Activity to access it.

Inside the Activity

```
private static Handler handler;


handler = new Handler();

handler().post(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        //ui stuff here :)
    }
});

public static Handler getHandler() {
   return handler;
}
```

Outside the Activity

```
MainActivity.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //ui stuff here :)
        }
    });
```